# Switch statement for range of sequential numbers

Tags: matlab, switch-statement

suppose when n is in the range of 80 to 90, I want it to print something.

```
n=input('Enter your marks: ');
switch n
    case n>=90
         fprintf('Grade : A');
    case (n>=80)
         fprintf('Grade : A');
end
```

but it does not work, neither the following:

```
switch n
    case 80:90
         fprintf('Grade : A');
    case 70:80
         fprintf('Grade : A');
end
```

I know that, puting  {80,81,82,83..} like this would solve the problem, but it does not look like the appropriate solution, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use if-else statement. Don't use switch statement. Switch is for one value(meaning if marks is equal to 80). You perform different statements for different value of marks. Since the mark value is in a range, use a if-else statement.

Example:

```
n=input('Enter your marks: ');
if  80 <= n a && n <= 90
         fprintf('Grade : A');
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally would always prefer a `switch-case` over `if-elseif-elseif....`, you just need to pass the values of `case` as a [**`comma separated list`**](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
n = 93;
points = 1:100;

points = num2cell(points);
switch n
    case {points{90:100}}
         fprintf('Grade : A');
    case {points{80:89}}
         fprintf('Grade : B');
    otherwise
        fprintf('Fail')
end
```

if have points with decimals, you need to decide whether you want to `round`, `floor` or `ceil` them. Students like `ceil` ;)

```
n = ceil(input('Enter your marks: '));
```

If you go with [lakesh's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26447669/2605073) you can consider using `break` statements in favor of more simple logical expressions.

```
if n >= 90;
   fprintf('Grade : A');
   break;
elseif n >= 80;
   fprintf('Grade : B');
   break;
elseif n >= 70;
   fprintf('Grade : C');
   break;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by constructing an array of score ranges:

```
S=[90,80,70,60,0];
```

and corresponding letter grades:

```
G=['A','B','C','D','F'];
```

Then, for a given score, find the first range value that is less than the score and use the index of that range value as the index to the letter grade array:

```
Grade=G(find(S(:)<=s,1))
```

For the input value `s=87`, the output is `Grade = B`.